# how to create inline array from spread of another array

Tags: arrays, list, go

I have this:

```
var conversationIds []string
```

but this doesn't seem to work:

```
for _, id := range []string{clientID, ...conversationIds}{
    s.consumeMessages(id)
}
```

not this:

```
for _, id := range []string{clientID, conversationIds...}{
    s.consumeMessages(id)
}
```

so what do I do?

Comment: It will probably help your searching to use the correct terms, what you have is a [slice](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Slice_types), not an [array](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Array_types) or a list.

Comment: Also style wise, the language and community tend to avoid trying to turn things into clever one-liners. Most programmers would have no problem encountering a temporary value to build the slice of the literal options or `append` got too cluttered, since it takes no extra heap allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `append`:

```
for _, id := range append([]string{clientID},conversationIds...) {
    s.consumeMessages(id)
}
```

Comment: boof thanks Burak, upvoted

Comment: @AlexanderMills if the order doesn't matter, you can also do `range append(conversationIds, clientID) {`

Comment: that's odd, I guess you could add one array to another, than it seems weird